# Load Assembly without culture and version

Tags: c#

I know that recommended way of loading assemblies is:

```
Assembly SampleAssembly = Assembly.Load
        ("SampleAssembly, Version=1.0.2004.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=8744b20f8da049e3")
```

But, what if I don't know which version of assembly exists in GAC (for example NpSql or MySql.Data can have different versions in different machines)?

Then I might want to load it without specifying version, culture and public key token.

Is that possible? (I know about LoadWithPartialName but it is now obsolete).

Comment: Quick Google search shows that it is possible (using `Assembly.Load(AssemblyName)` overload), but not recommended. See [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yx7xezcf(v=vs.110).aspx), [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x4cw969y(v=vs.110).aspx) and [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd153782(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems we can use Assembly.Load(AssemblyName) but it is not recommended way to do it.